# Cucumber reports are getting generated but deleted when the app is uninstalled after the test

Tags: android, reporting, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I´m running cucumber tests in Android and trying to store the report in the external directory which seems to be `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package-name>/files`.

During the test execution, I can see the reports getting generated. But the reports are deleted when the app gets uninstalled. I´m using the below Gradle task to copy reports which isn't working.

```
gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { task, state ->
    if ((task == connectedAndroidTest) || (task == connectedCheck)) {
    enter code here    def reportDir = new File(project.buildDir, "cucumber-reports")
        if (!reportDir.exists()) {
            reportDir.mkdirs()
        }
        println 'Retrieving Cucumber test report to ' + project.buildDir
        def processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
                ['adb', 'pull', '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package-name>/files/reports/', reportDir.getAbsolutePath()])
        processBuilder.start()
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me copy the reports to the desktop before they get deleted.

I have tried to store the reports in a couple of other locations such as `/sdcard`, `/mnt/sdcard`, `/storage/emulated/0`. I haven't had luck with any of these. I get IOException. It seems that I don't have permissions to write to these locations.

Answer (score 0):

Because the data are app data and all app data will be removed during the uninstallation process of the app. You need the permissions to write at the local storage.

```
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
    {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    } 
    else 
    {
        // You have permissions
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) 
{
   if((requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) 
    {
        // You have permissions
    }
}
```

And you have to add the permission request to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You can write the internal storage if you have the permissions.

```
File file = new File(<SomePath>, <SomeName>);
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) 
{
    // Save data
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    // Error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @kampi. But this is test automation and i am using cucumber.  and i don't really have an activity that tries to store something on the device in which case the code above makes sense. How can i use this in test automation.